# initially load a page with the BrowserField and then have links clicked in that open up in the BB browser instead of the BrowserField?

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I want to initially load a page (stored html page) with the BrowserField and then have links clicked in that open up in the BB browser instead of the BrowserField?

My current code is as following,

```
BrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, new BrowserFieldController()
  {                 
     public InputConnection handleResourceRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws    Exception {
        return (InputConnection)Connector.open(request.getURL());
     }
     public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception 
     {
         BrowserSession b = Browser.getDefaultSession();
         b.displayPage(request.getURL());   
     }  
 });
```

And I want to load the html page stored in resources in browserfield and then open the links from the page in BB Browser which I'm doing using 
    browserfield.requestContent("local:///test.html");

But application tries to open the html file in browser, which is not desirable.

Please suggest me a workaround,

Thanks,
Aniket

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite easy to achieve.

- Firstly you will need to use the BrowserField object instead.
- Extend the browser field's javascript engine, by using BrowserField.extendScriptEngine(String name, Scriptable scriptable)
- Within the Scriptable you will open the native browser.
- In the html, make the buttons execute the extended javascript function you created.

Answer (score 0):

The handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) method is called each time the browserfield requests content.
Add a count inside the method.
Increment the count by 1 each time the method is called.

If the count is greater then 0, it means the Browserfield has already loaded the first time. Subsequent calls to the method should then open a browser session instead of requesting content inside the Browserfield.

```
public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception 
     {
        if(click<1){
          // request for content inside Browserfield
          }
         else  {
         BrowserSession b = Browser.getDefaultSession();
         b.displayPage(request.getURL()); 
         }

       click++;  
     }
```